# React: Updating States/Var mid-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

Hi I'm looking for some help on how I can update a variable or state in the middle of a react component.

The loading overlay needs to use a variable to tell how long for it to go for (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-overlay). I want that variable to be false once the Card image has been loaded. I have provided my code but am unsure how I can update the state of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Photography.css";
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import img from "./img";

function Image() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  return (
    <LoadingOverlay
      active={!loaded}
      spinner
      text='Loading your content...'
      >
        <p>content is here</p>
        <Card bg="dark">
            <Card.Img src={img} style={loaded ? {} : { display: 'none' }} onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} onClick={handleShow} alt="test"/>
        </Card>
    </LoadingOverlay>
  );
}
export default Image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is that Card component coming from? Assuming that `onLoad` is being called correctly and the overlay component works, this looks fine. I would add `onLoad={console.log}`and see if that is behaving the way you want it to, or check that Card.Img component for an onError prop or something like it that might give you some more helpful errors.